# Quitar y agregar clase al dar clic en el otro elemento

Tags: html, jquery, css

Asi me agrega la clase si le doy clic a la lista.

lo que deseo realizar es que al darle clic a la otra lista se le agregue la clase y se le remueva a la otra, ya sea que hayan mas listas.

Como podria hacerlo?

```
<div class="caracteristicas">
 <ul>
   <li class="icon icon-1">Automatico</li>
   <li class="icon icon-2">120 CC</li>
   <li class="icon icon-3">4x2</li>
   <li class="icon icon-4">Gasolina</li>
   <li class="icon icon-5">Gasolina</li>
   <li class="icon icon-6">Gasolina</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
  <li class="icon icon-1">Automatico</li>
  <li class="icon icon-2">120 CC</li>
  <li class="icon icon-3">4x2</li>
  <li class="icon icon-4">Gasolina</li>
  <li class="icon icon-5">Gasolina</li>
  <li class="icon icon-6">Gasolina</li>
  </ul>
</div>

$(".caracteristicas ul" ).click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En el click() puedes limpiar antes las clases a todos los elementos ul y despues asignarla a la actual, como ya lo tienes.

```
$(".caracteristicas ul").click(function() {
   $(".caracteristicas ul").removeClass("selected");
   $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```